# How to understand this three things present in every free proxy list site?

Tags: proxy

I have a doubt what are this three things present in any free proxy list site: **anonymity level**, **Uptime (L/D)** & **Responses time**?

To avoid confusion I marked with **Red Box** in this image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymity Level will be the amount of filtering of information that the proxy server does - for example, ddoes it add an X-FORWARDED-FOR header with the IP you actually come from?

The Uptime is how long the proxy has been available for - a measure of how reliable it is.

The responses time will be some measure of how long it takes to get pages and return them to the test site. The response time by itself is meaningless unless the numbers are very high, but this could be an indication as to how well connected the site is, how much bandwidth it has etc.  If you are located near the site doing the testing then the lower this figure the faster pages will load.